# 'powershell.exeA' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: powershell, nrpe

I am running into a bit of a problem when attempting to use Powershell with NRPE. Now I ran this command,

```
command[alias_check_commerce_log]=cmd /c echo C:\Program Files\nrpe\plugins\file_checker.ps1; exit($LastExitCode) | powershell.exe -command -
```

in `cmd` and it went through without a hitch. Just when I call it via Icinga, for some odd reason, it spits out `'powershell.exeA'` is not recognized as an internal or external command. Now I know the A is not supposed to be sitting with powershell.exe, so how would I keep this from happening? Keep in mind that the command is the same in the config as posted here. Checked all text in hopes of it just being a simple Typo. I just can't seem to wrap my head around this one and figure out how to keep this from happening. Any and all help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: can you make the question readable?

Answer (score 0):

Probably file encoding. You likely copy/pasted the command line from a web site or something, and there is a special character after `.exe`.

Open the file where that command is defined in an editor that supports different encodings and hopefully one that can show whitespace and "special" characters, and inspect the file.

Or Start over and manually type the commands.